# How to order by in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Show the 1984 winners and subject ordered by subject and winner name; but list Chemistry and Physics last.
There is a hint but I have no idea how to use it: The expression subject IN ('Chemistry','Physics') can be used as a value - it will be 0 or 1.

```
 SELECT winner, subject, subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry')
      FROM nobel
     WHERE yr=1984
     ORDER BY subject,winner
```

How can I modify this to get a correct answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT winner, subject
FROM nobel
WHERE yr=1984
ORDER BY (subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry')) ASC, subject, winner
```

The first part of the `ORDER BY` returns 0 if subject is not in the given list, else it returns 1. Ordering by this expression first will ensure 'Physics' and 'Chemistry' records are listed last.
Then everything is ordered by subject and winner.